# Using function stored in other local files of same directory

Tags: c++

I've this following code in C++:

```
//file0.cpp
 #include "file11.cpp"
 #include "file22.cpp"

 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>

 using namespace std;

 extern void func1(int i);
 extern void func2(int i);

 int main(void)
 {
    int i;
    func1(i);
    func2(i);

    cout<<"the value of i is"<<" "<<i;

    getch();
    return 0;
  }
```

//file11.cpp

```
 #inluce<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>
 using namespace std;
 void func1(int i)
 {
    cout<<++i;

 }
```

//file22.cpp

```
 #inluce<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>
 using namespace std;
 void func2(int i)
 {
    cout<<++i;

 }
```

I'm using Dev-C++ compiler, on Windows Vista - 32bits.
I'm trying to pass int i from file0.cpp to the function func1(int ) and func2(int). But while i compile this code, it shows error.

the error logs are as follows:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp" -o "C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
In file included from C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp:1:
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file11.cpp:1:2: invalid preprocessing directive #inluce
In file included from C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp:1:
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file11.cpp: In function `void func1(int)':
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file11.cpp:6: error: `cout' undeclared (first use this function)
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file11.cpp:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

In file included from C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp:2:
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file22.cpp:1:2: invalid preprocessing directive #inluce
In file included from C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp:2:
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file22.cpp: In function `void func2(int)':
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\/file22.cpp:6: error: `cout' undeclared (first use this function)

C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp: In function `int main()':
C:\Users\samurai\Documents\file0.cpp:17: error: `cout' undeclared (first use this function)

Execution terminated
```

I'm unable to debug this code. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: The ability to debug is nothing compared to the ability to *read*. When it says, "invalid preprocessing directive #inluce", that should have given you a hint...

Comment: In the future, consider paying attention to the errors and warnings of your compiler: "invalid preprocessing directive #inluce" (preceded by the filename and line number) is quite explicit here. Error messages do take some getting used to, but they have their pay-offs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are typing `#inluce` and not `#include` on your source files

When a compiler tells you something, it is usually important :P

**EDIT** When reading compiler errors, start with the first one, *not* the last one, and fix it. Do not attempt to correct the second one because most of the time it is a side effect of the first error. Then try to compile it again.

Takes a little practice, just don't be scared of the wall of text it throws at you.

Comment: i would rather say...please look at the codes given above ...i have written #include there but the compiler is giving error writing it as #incluce...

Comment: Well, I would say read your code again. You clearly do not have #include written in all places.

Comment: Thanks..my fault..i corrected it out..but now i have a new problem now i am passing a static value defined in file0.cpp to the functions defined in file11.cpp and file22.cpp.

According to concepts of static variable it should not be accessible in functions defined in other file but here i am getting the output..although the output suggests that function is not treating it as a static variable but a normal int..

Answer (score 1):

You spelled `#include` wrong.  Fix that and see what errors you get after that.